# beautifulsoup getting an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' from a div's child's text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The HTML looks a little like this: (there's a vast many more stats etc, but this is the first one)

```
<div id="statistics-content">
<div class="statTextGroup">
<div class="statText statText--homeValue">53%</div>
<div class="statText statText--titleValue">Ball Possession</div>
<div class="statText statText--awayValue">47%</div>
</div>
```

I'd like to draw out the 53% (without the % symbol if possible) as a home team value.
Then I'd like to draw out the 47% (also without the % symbol if possible) as the away team value.

I can add the Ball Possession words later - or, if there's an easy way to append Ball Possession from this list, then I will do that too.

So, I did try this:

```
home_stats = soup.select_one('#statistics-content .statText--homeValue:nth-child(1)').text
```

And I searched the resultant error:

```
home_stats = soup.select_one('#statistics-content .statText--homeValue:nth-child(1)').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

But I can not seem to find something that fits this particular situation. My previous attempts have worked using this similar method, but they were either in a span or an a tag and had attributes. But this is just text wrapped in a div.

I can not change the HTML (sadly) - so I need to parse it directly from that HTML if possible.

The final outcome should look like:

[home_team] had 53% ball possession and [away_team] had 47% ball possession

Both home and away team works to give the correct name. I'd like "ball possession" to be all lower case and I'd like to add the % myself as I want to use those numbers separately later.

The code is all there, just not scraping the correct data. There's 14 other stats I'd like to retrieve, so hopefully, if I get this one right, then nth-child(x) should work.

Thanks kindly - this is very much my beginning journey of python and webscraping, so all help is appreciated.

To make it easier, I am scraping now from this site: https://www.scoreboard.com/en/match/SO3Fg7NR/#match-statistics;0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will get you started.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sample_html = """<div id="statistics-content">
<div class="statTextGroup">
<div class="statText statText--homeValue">53%</div>
<div class="statText statText--titleValue">Ball Possession</div>
<div class="statText statText--awayValue">47%</div>
</div>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(sample_html, "html.parser")

stats = [
    soup.select_one(f'#statistics-content .statText--{value}').getText(strip=True)
    for value in ["homeValue", "awayValue"]
]
outcome = "[home_team] had {} ball possession and [away_team] had {} ball possession".format(*stats)
print(outcome)
```

Output:

```
[home_team] had 53% ball possession and [away_team] had 47% ball possession
```

EDIT:

Thanks for the URL! It turns out there's nothing wrong with your code. The content of the page is behind `JS`, so `BeautifulSoup` won't see it. However, there are other ways to get what you're after.

One way of doing this, would be with [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and [chrome driver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads). In other words, this is an automation framework which allows us to execute test across various browsers or... scrape websites.

Here's what I've come up with:

```
import time

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from tabulate import tabulate


options = Options()
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# Use the web browser to access the url
driver.get("https://www.scoreboard.com/en/match/SO3Fg7NR/#match-statistics;0")
# wait for all the elements to load
time.sleep(2)

# Use BS4 to parse the page source obtained by the driver
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

# Close the web browser
driver.close()


# This is used to build a list of text values from all tags
def grab_tags(css_selector: str) -> list:
    return [t.getText(strip=True) for t in soup.select(css_selector)]


headers = grab_tags(".detail-experimental .statText--titleValue")
home_team = grab_tags(".detail-experimental .statText--homeValue")
away_team = grab_tags(".detail-experimental .statText--awayValue")

# glue all text items together per stat tab
# A list of tuples -> [(Ball Possesion, 53%, 47%), (Goal Attempts, 10, 5)...]
match_data = list(zip(headers, home_team, away_team))

split_value = 15
# split match data list stat table -> there are 15 items per table -> 3 tables
statistics = [
    match_data[i:i+split_value] for i in range(0, len(match_data), split_value)
]

# three stat tables
match, first_half, second_half = statistics

# print any of them
print(tabulate(match, headers=["Stat:", "Home Team", "Away Team"]))
```

Output:

```
Stat:              Home Team    Away Team
-----------------  -----------  -----------
Ball Possession    53%          47%
Goal Attempts      10           5
Shots on Goal      2            1
Shots off Goal     4            2
Blocked Shots      4            2
Free Kicks         11           10
Corner Kicks       8            2
Offsides           2            1
Goalkeeper Saves   0            2
Fouls              8            10
Yellow Cards       1            0
Total Passes       522          480
Tackles            15           12
Attacks            142          105
Dangerous Attacks  44           29
```

Note: I do realize this might blow your mind if you're at the beginning of your web-scraping journey, but I've put some comments to explain what's going on. Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, I am going to give this a try, but there's several other .statText values that I want to get too - so how do I append the nth-child to this?

Comment: Could you extend the example of the html in your question with those other stats you're after and a desired outcome?

Comment: Yeah, sure... can I just give a link? I found a site I'd like to scrape for this. here's the example I am now choosing to use: https://www.scoreboard.com/en/match/SO3Fg7NR/#match-statistics;0

Comment: So I have the score, the home and away team sorted, but the remaining stats like goals, ball possession etc... that's what I am working to get.

Comment: oh wow!!! It's going to take me a while to process this so I am copying it in to try and work backwards. Thank you for doing that, that's simply amazing! 

I won't get a chance to check it now for about 24 hours, but I will credit you! Thanks again.

Comment: I'll take a good look at this tomorrow, I think it does work, but I am getting errors. But it looks perfect. Smaller than what I am about to embark on :) 

Thanks again for the effort you put in, this is truly amazing!

Comment: I think I might be missing modules or something here.

Some of the errors I get: line 14, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

Comment: line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()

Comment: And: line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

There's a web address to the chrome site, but it doesn't seem to tell me what I am missing here.

Comment: You have to install the chrome driver and the selenium module. Follow the links I included in the answer.

Comment: I had installed both though... so I thought. I will check again.

Comment: I installed again and restarted - but still getting multiple errors

Comment: From what I am reading it appears that it is all to do with paths and somehow my standard install and VS Code aren't really talking to each other. It might take a while to fix all these - but it could also be worth it.

Comment: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

So I need to find the path... but I actually don't know the path it is looking for. I have the executable - but where do I put it haha... I'll get there. This is fun.

Comment: The PATH depends on your system. I'm on Linux but this might help you http://www.automationtestinghub.com/download-chrome-driver/

Comment: I think I am close: driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='Users\[my user name]\Documents\Python\chromedriver.exe')
 But this doesn't work (yet)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222462/discussion-between-paul-davis-and-baduker).

Answer (score 1):

The data is loaded dynamically so Beautiful doesn't see the information inside the page. You can use this script to retrieve the data with BeautifulSoup:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.scoreboard.com/en/match/SO3Fg7NR/#match-statistics;0'

headers = {'X-Fsign':'SW9D1eZo'}
match_id = re.search(r'match/([^/]+)/', url).group(1)
data_url = 'https://d.scoreboard.com/en/x/feed/d_st_{match_id}_en_1'.format(match_id=match_id)

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(data_url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

# locate row, that contains "Ball Possession":
row = soup.select_one('.statRow:has(*:contains("Ball Possession"))')

home_value = row.select_one('.statText--homeValue').text.replace('%', '')
away_value = row.select_one('.statText--awayValue').text.replace('%', '')

print(home_value, away_value)
```

Prints:

```
53 47
```

Comment: Can you help me understand what this line and the following 2 lines are:

headers = {'X-Fsign':'SW9D1eZo'}

Comment: @PaulDavis This is HTTP header used by the script to obtain correct information. The remote site probably uses it to filter-out automatic bots. I found this variable by looking into Firefox Developer Tools -> Network tab.